# Why do $4\cdot 2^n\sin\frac{45}{2^n}$, $2\cdot 2^n\sin\frac{90}{2^n}$, and $1\cdot 2^n\sin\frac{180}{2^n}$ all tend to $\pi$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, pi

I am not sure what question or inquiries to ask actually, but I just think this is really awesome

> Can someone explain to me why the graphs of
>   $$4\cdot 2^n\sin\frac{45}{2^n}, \qquad 2\cdot 2^n\sin\frac{90}{2^n}, \qquad\text{and}\qquad 1\cdot 2^n\sin\frac{180}{2^n}$$ 
>   all tend to $\pi$?

[image: Please Sign here and Sin here XD]

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3056784/n-tends-to-infinity-trigo

Answer (score 2):

Because $\sin x \approx x$ when $x$ is small and measured in radians.  When $x$ is measured in degrees $\sin x \approx \frac {\pi x}{180}.$  When $n$ gets large the argument of $\sin$ becomes small.

Comment: (+1) Just to clarify, saying that $\sin x \approx x$ when $x$ is small is an informal way for saying that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\sin h}h  = 1$.

Hence \begin{align}\lim_{n \to \infty}4 \cdot 2^n \cdot \sin\left(\frac{45^\circ}{2^n}\right)&=\lim_{n \to \infty}4 \cdot 2^n \cdot \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+2}}\right) \\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}4 \cdot 2^n \cdot \frac{\pi}{2^{n+2}}\cdot \frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+2}}\right)}{\frac{\pi}{2^{n+2}}} \\
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}4 \cdot 2^n \cdot \frac{\pi}{2^{n+2}}\cdot \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2^{n+2}}\right)}{\frac{\pi}{2^{n+2}}} \\
&= \pi \cdot 1\\
&= \pi\end{align}

Similarly for the other sequences.

That is we have

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}w \cdot 2^n \cdot \sin \left( \frac{180^\circ}{w\cdot 2^n}\right)=\pi$$

Comment: Thanks again Siong! :D

Comment: so does this work for other series as well?

Comment: nb: $\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(h)}{h} = 1$, not 0.

Comment: oops, thanks for pointing out the typo.